# How to convert tera::Error to actix_web::Error?

Tags: rust, actix-web, tera

I'm studying `rust`/`actix`/`tera` and cannot figure out how to implement `ResponseError` trait on the `tera::Error`, or alternatively how to convert `tera::Error` to `actix_web::Error`.

With the following code snippet:

```
match TEMPLATES.render("index.html", &ctx) {
    Ok(s) => Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().body(s)),
    Err(e) => Err(e),
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
mismatched types

expected struct `actix_web::Error`, found struct `tera::Error`rustc(E0308)
main.rs(71, 23): expected struct `actix_web::Error`, found struct `tera::Error`
```

So I tried the following:

```
match TEMPLATES.render("index.html", &ctx) {
    Ok(s) => Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().body(s)),
    Err(e) => Err(e.into()),
}
```

But in this case I get:

```
the trait bound `tera::Error: actix_web::ResponseError` is not satisfied

the trait `actix_web::ResponseError` is not implemented for `tera::Error`

note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::From<tera::Error>` for `actix_web::Error`
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<actix_web::Error>` for `tera::Error`rustc(E0277)
main.rs(71, 25): the trait `actix_web::ResponseError` is not implemented for `tera::Error`
```

So finally I've tried:

```
use actix_web::{get, post, web, error, Error, ResponseError,
    HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpServer,
    App, Responder};
use tera::{Tera, Context};
use tera;

impl ResponseError for tera::Error {}
```

But now getting:

```
only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types

impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate

note: define and implement a trait or new type insteadrustc(E0117)
main.rs(12, 1): impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
main.rs(12, 24): `tera::Error` is not defined in the current crate
```

Function signature in which I have the `match` block is the following:

```
#[get("/")]
async fn tst() -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Error: _only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types_ This means you can't, you might want to change your question as how to convert `tera::Error` to `actix_web::Error`, or unite them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already discovered, `into()` cannot be used to convert the `tera::Error` to an `actix_web::Error` because no such conversion is directly defined. In this case it gives you a slightly misleading error - because this conversion exists:

```
impl<T> From<T> for Error
where
    T: 'static + ResponseError,
```

The compiler throws an error saying that if only the tera error implemented `ResponseError`, it could do the conversion. But you cannot make it implement that trait, because of the 'trait orphan rule', which says that you cannot implement a trait from outside your own crate onto a type from outside your own crate.

You could wrap the `tera::Error` in your own struct, and then implement `ResponseError` for that, as [outlined in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own).

But there is a simpler solution: actix-web provides a [whole swathe of helper functions](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.3.2/actix_web/error/index.html#functions) for converting errors, which you can use like so:

```
match TEMPLATES.render("index.html", &ctx) {
    Ok(s) => Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().body(s)),
    Err(e) => Err(error::ErrorInternalServerError(e)),
}
```

The provided helpers map the supplied error into the named HTTP response code, so you can pick one that most closely represents the error that occurred.

See also the actix-web [documentation for error handling](https://actix.rs/docs/errors/).

Caveat Emptor: this solution is untested and I have never used `tera` nor `actix-web`, rather I gleaned this from skimming their documentation.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the efforts! If you would update your answer by changing the match `Err` arm to `Err(e) => Err(error::ErrorInternalServerError(e))` I would happily accept it.

Comment: @NarūnasK have done, although note it is still valid without that if you `use error::ErrorInternalServerError;` in your file